# When the user clicks the right answer, it will move on to the next question

Tags: java, shapes, mouselistener

I design a program, that every time you click on a shape, it will change color in a orderly fashion. If you look at my code below I do not know what to put in my if statement. I want to return a value(int value if possible) to my main method so it knows to move on to the next question.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { //when user clicks a button it goes in here

    k++; //increases k, every time it runs
    if (k == 4) //if k equal 4, it will go back to 0. Repeats the cycle
        k = 0;

    Point p = e.getPoint(); //get the postion of the click
    Polygon[] polys = polygonPanel.polygons;

    for (j = 0; j < polys.length; j++) { //check which polygon is picked
        if (polys[j].contains(p)) { //if the user clicks a shape it will go in this loop to change color    
            polygonPanel.colors[j] = getColor(k); //bring the four colors from the method
            polygonPanel.repaint(); //change the color of the polygon when clicked
            /*if (rightAnswer) {
                correctAnswer++;
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to become familiar with the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that handles correct answers, and insert the macro after the `correctAnswer++` line.

For example, we could do:

```
public void handleAnswer (int correctAnswer) {
    moveToNextQuestion(correctAnswer); //Takes the correct answer and moves to the question with the value "correctAnswer"
}
```

Then, in the `moveToNextQuestion` function, you would add the code that switches questions.